# Compile AS3 into a SWF online using Flex SDK's mxmlc

Tags: php, flash, compiler-construction, mxmlc, apache-flex

**Read my question thoroughly before responding, I know there’s a site called [wonderfl.net](http://wonderfl.net/)**

I‘ve got the Flex SDK 4 on my Mac and I found a way to compile AS3 into SWF files using Flex's mxmlc compiler in Xcode, so I wondered, would it be possible to do this sort of simply online? Using for example a language I'm familiar with, PHP?

I thought it’d be a thing that would be interesting to use for a website, or like some private projects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the available tools to do so.  You can write the AS3 content posted from the web into files, use PHP's `exec` function to run `mxmlc`, then send the resulting .SWF file to the client using PHP's `readfile` function.  You'd just have to make sure mxmlc was present on the web server running the PHP.